# Osm2pgsql - Lines instead of polygons that represent buildings

Tags: postgis, polygon, linestring, osm2pgsql, address

So I am using a PostgreSQL database with the PostGIS extension to extract building data with addresses from osm data.

I just discovered that in my dataset, imported with osm2pgsql of the german city hamburg there are some entries in planet_osm_line which have addresses. Those entries are also valid polygons, i tried to transform those LINESTRINGs with ST_MakePolygon and that worked for every entry.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:
[image: Not rendered building.]

So I wondered why osm2pgsql did not interpret them as polygons. To my understanding a valid polygon (closed way) needs identical start and end nodes, which is so far true for every entry.

I might be missing something here, so can anyone with more experience can explain this to me?

Here is the text representation of the geometry from above:
[image]

Comment: Is it some building with an interior open area or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackExchange GIS!

It looks like the difference is the tagging of the buildings. Way [171640616](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/171640616) is `building:demolished=yes` whereas way [171640812](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/171640812) is just `building=yes`.

If you look at the [default style](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style) for osm2pgsql, the default settings for `building` as a tag are to create a polygon (see the [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Import_style) for further details on how this works), but in the first case this tag does not exist, so the `addr:housenumber` entry is dominant, which is set to linear, which explains the geometry you are getting.